# error line: 76 compiler: expected identifier before '(' token

Tags: c

I'm a complete noob when it comes to coding, You pro's will most likely laugh at how pathetic this was ;).

Anyways, I'm coding a script for a game. I'm getting this error `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scripts\main.c(76): error line: 76 compiler: expected identifier before '(' token.` Now I've looked over it for nearly 2 hours now, I've also had a friend look at from a different location for an hour; neither of us are very good at coding but we are learning slowly.

Extract from script

```
        teleport_char(GetPlayerPed(),2276.3477,72.9833,5.8128,327.0000); //Teleport yourself to x,y,z,h
        while(true){//While SCO Is on
            if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed)) && (IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN)){ //If you are in a police car and press dpad down
                if(!IS_CHAR_MODEL(GetPlayerPed,4111764146)){ //If you are not the cop model
                    GET_CAR_CHAR_IS_USING(GetPlayerPed,PoliceV); //Get your car and store handle in PoliceV
                    LoadModel();//Go to LoadModel Void function Line: 52
                    WARP_CHAR_INTO_CAR(GetPlayerPed,PoliceV){ //Once Load Model Is done Warp back into police vehicle
                else{
                    CLEAR_PRINTS();
                    TERMINATE_THIS_SCRIPT();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line 76 is if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHI 
Hope you pro's will help such a noob, Cheers in advance everyone.

Comment: Which of these lines is line 76?

Comment: Line 76 is if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHI
Line 80 is WARP_CHAR_INTO_CAR(GetPlayerPed,PoliceV){
After using all three answere they resulted in the same error

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scripts\main.c(80): error line: 80 compiler:
 expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: the name `IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE` points toward a mix between problem and program domains.

Answer (score 4):

You have mismatched parentheses

You effectively have

```
 if (a) && (b)
```

instead of

```
 if (a && b)
```

Change this:

```
        if(IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed)) && (IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN)){ //If you are in a police car and press dpad down
```

to this:

```
        if (IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed) && IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN)) { //If you are in a police car and press dpad down
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have to change `()`

```
if( IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed) && IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN) ){
```

or more readable

```
if( 
    IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed) 
    && IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN) 
){
```

**edit:**

error in line 80 - correct line:

```
WARP_CHAR_INTO_CAR(GetPlayerPed,PoliceV);
```

**edit:**

Wait, I see another problem in line 81 - closing `}` - correct line:

```
} else {
```

**edit:**

I think you have to much closing `}`. I think you can delete first `}` below `TERMINATE_THIS_SCRIPT();`. But first try to compile it before you delete this `}`.

**by the way:** learn `C` harder because some problems are so elementary that it is shame to ask for help.

Comment: @johnchen902 Redundant syntax is never preferable. If you don't trust the macro, fix the macro.

Comment: it looks like `johnchen902` disappeared.

Comment: All 3 answers resulted in the following error...
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scripts\main.c(80): error line: 80 compiler:
 expected ';' before '{' token

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ( and ) on that line of code.

```
if((IS_CHAR_IN_ANY_POLICE_VEHICLE(GetPlayerPed)) && (IS_BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED(0,DPAD_DOWN))){
```